# UK visitor Visa & Brexit

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, visa

I'll admit that the subject that I'm trying to unveil might be a little bit shallow, but I hope that it'll make some sense nonetheless.

I'll be applying next year early January for the uk standard visitor Visa with an invitation from a cousin whom is a legal British citizen (have incomes, a roof..etc), I am Algerian, i am a student in 3rd grade, I want to experience travelling, both of my parents are from the working layer, I'll be bringing a considerably large file filled with documents of every sort (mortgage,land ownings,incomes..etc) and also some documents from my cousin that lives in the UK (child benefit, bank statements) to prove that I and him have a steady life and that I by no means intend to remain in the UK after my time of visit, that's the part that I will try by all my power to prove.

Now for the part of my question, I'm very concerned about the UK political situation in 2019 as I intended (decision made early in the summer 2018 with my cousin) to come to the UK from the 15th March to 1st April (mid term holidays) and have some time with him. now, with all the stories about how much the borders will tighten towards EU and all the scramble that will fall upon outsiders in general,I fear that my application will not be even looked on.

I'm trying hard to follow every step that the UK takes towards visas etc.. but I fear that this will be not enough and that all my effort will vanish as they'll refuse my application.

What is your opinion and if you have concrete facts, please feel free to share them.

And thank you.

Comment: Seems off-topic... I think you will get better answers if you ask it in Travel.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about obtaining a long-term visa. Hence, it better fits at [expats.se].

Comment: @bytebuster I sense sarcasm and I gladly approve it, thanks for the giggle I guess, don't worry I'll delete it myself because I had already good answers on travel SE

Answer (score 2):

Brexit is all about the future relationship between the UK (and its citizens) and the EU (and its citizens). Any outcome is very unlikely to affect UK Visas granted or refused to citizens of other countries entirely (such as, to choose an example at random, Algerians).

That's not to say that in future, or even in parallel, there won't be such changes. Just that changes to the UK's Visa policies towards Algerians is not likely to be affected directly.

However, as with any guess about the future, this answer has the potential to be entirely wrong.